# Page is refreshing after putting CKEditor

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

The code below shows that I have a pageblocktable that contains a column of a ckeditor which is a long text. I want to rerender it within the same page by adding of a new row using the button **Add Row**. Whenever I tried to click on the **Add Row** button, the page always refresh and the values of the recently added rows was disappeared. Is there a way that the value of the long text will not disappear and will not refresh the page? Thanks.

```
            <apex:column headerValue="Action">
                <apex:commandLink value="Delete" style="Button" action="{!delWrapper}" reRender="wtable">
                   <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="theBlock" oncomplete="ReloadCkEditor();"/>
                   <apex:param name="toDelIdent" value="{!pw.ident}" assignTo="{!toDelIdent}"/> 
                </apex:commandLink>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Company Name">
                <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredInput" layout="block">
                   <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredBlock" layout="block"/>
                       <apex:inputField value="{!pw.peforWrapper.Name}"/>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:column>

            <apex:column headerValue="Job Description" id="col">
                <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredInput" layout="block" >
                   <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredBlock" layout="block" />
                   <apex:outputPanel id="JDPanel">
                   <apex:inputtextarea id="oNextSteps1" styleClass="ckeditor" value="{!pw.peforWrapper.Job_Description__c}"/>
                    <script>
                        CKEDITOR.replace('{!$Component.oNextSteps1}',{
                            width: '100%',
                            height: 120,
                            removeButtons: 'Link,Unlink,Cut,Copy,Paste,Undo,Redo,Strike,Subscript,Superscript,Anchor,About'
                        }

                        );
                    </script>

                   </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

```
<-----FRONT END SCRIPT----->
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <apex:includescript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.CKEditor, 'ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js')}" />
  <apex:includescript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.CKEditor, 'ckeditor/ckeditor.js')}" />


<!---- ADD ROWS ----->
public void addRows(){
      for (Integer idx=0; idx<addCount; idx++){
       prWrapper.add(new ProfExpWrapper(nextIdent++));
      }
 }


<!---- WRAPPER ----->
public class ProfExpWrapper{
      public Professional_Experience__c peforWrapper {get;set;}
      public Integer ident {get;set;}

      public ProfExpWrapper(Integer inIdent, Professional_Experience__c professionalExperience){
           ident=inIdent;
           peforWrapper= professionalExperience;
      }

      public ProfExpWrapper(Integer inIdent){
          ident=inIdent;
          peforWrapper= new Professional_Experience__c();
      }
 }
```

Comment: Where is add button's code?

Comment: I already added the add button's code above. Thanks.

Comment: Yyou have not added visualforce page code from where you are calling the method.